# Messing around with easy bcd, messed up MBR

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8, easybcd

So, last night i was messing around with easyBCD 2.2 trying to repair my legacy win8 MBR when i messed it up even worse.

Before, when i started it it would go straight to GRUB2 and would boot into ubuntu, but not windows 8 (The boot configuration files are missing or contain errors). Now, when trying to boot legacy, instead of grub menu, i get "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key".

I could not originally boot into windows 8, but i fixed that with `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootrec /rebuild bcd` and `/fixboot`.
Any way to fix?

Answer (score 0):

After you fixed the Windows boot files with `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootrec /rebuildbcd` and `/fixboot` commands, you have to run boot-repair.It will install grub2 on your disk and make the appearance of both Ubuntu and Windows options on startup(Grub screen).

Comment: I tried that, it still won't start.

Comment: It's not that GRUB won't detect it, it's that the bios is not pointing it to my hard drive. When i tried boot-repair all it did was make a new efi file and reinstall grub to it.

Comment: Post the boot repair log.